# How to draw 3D mathematical models in .NET? What 3D engine would best suitable to do this effectively?

Tags: .net, wpf, math, graphics, 3d

I recently faced a problem of presenting the output of simple genetic algorithm that looks for extremes of 2 argument function f(x1,x2) . I would like to be able to use x1 as x, x2 as y and f as z and to draw points in 3d space that I could rotate. ( I'm currently drawing this on bitmap using color as the 'z axis'.)

Where should I start?

UPDATE:

I found a directory of [3D engines for C#](http://www.devmaster.net/engines/list.php?fid=6&sid=2) but there are a lot to choose from... Could you advise if any one of them would be best for my problem?

UPDATE 2:

Thanks to Cameron's suggestion a 3D options in WPF seem to be suiting my needs. I will give it a try for sure.

I am reposting his links here:
    [<strike>* WPF 3D Tutorial</strike>](http://www.kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm)
    [* CodeProject: WPF 3D Primer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Wpf3DPrimer.aspx)
    [* CodeProject: WPF 3D : Part 1 of n](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF3D_1.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use WPF at all, then you can do some pretty easy simple stuff right away.

Here's some links to get started:

- [WPF 3D Tutorial](http://www.kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm)
- [CodeProject: WPF 3D Primer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Wpf3DPrimer.aspx)
- [CodeProject: WPF 3D : Part 1 of n](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF3D_1.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There is tao framework if you would like to do tings from scratch, like me. It is a opengl framework(with more) for C#. [taoframework link](http://taoframework.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I use OpenInventor for scientific visualisation. It may be (in some ways) a relic of the old SGI days, but it is still being supported and works well. Regarding graphing and other scientific visualisation, look at MeshViz and other extensions from Mercury:

- [Mercury (formerly TGS) OpenInventor](http://www.tgs.com/)
- [MeshViz extension](http://www.tgs.com/products/oiv_mesh_viz_overview.asp)

It has charting, vector visualisation, etc. It's quite comprehensive.

It's not free, but they do trial licenses so you can determine if it suits your needs.

Comment: oops - forgot to explicitly mention that there are .Net bindings available from Mercury that work quite well.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer coding OpenGL directly (instead of using an engine), check out [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com) or the [Tao Framework](http://www.taoframework.com). Both use the same codebase, but OpenTK follows .Net conventions more closely and is easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

wpf + managed dx.